# Запись файлов в android api Q, которые сохранятся при удалении приложения

Tags: android, kotlin, хранение-данных, android-scoped-storage

Хочу сделать фичу резервного копирования некоторых настроек приложения в файл, чтобы после удаления или  установки на новое устройство у пользователя была возможность восстановить свой прогресс из файла лежащего в памяти устройства.

Проблема в том что привычный `getExternalStorageDirectory()` в android 10 стал `deprecated`, и использовать его не получается.
Все, что я нашел записывает файлы в папки, которые удаляются вместе с приложением. Да, с этими файлами можно взаимодействовать через проводник, но это будет неудобно каждому пользователю.

Есть ли способ записи файла в папку, которая не удалится вместе с приложением?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, можно. Для этого вам надо получить пермишен на каталог, куда вы собираетесь писать. В терминах [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage) делается это так:

1)Сначала запрашиваем пермишен на чтение запись, для чего запускаем `Intent`:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION  |
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION  |
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FOLDER);
```

2)При запуске `Intent` у юзера будет запрошен каталог и разрешение на чтение/запись, после выбора юзером каталога, выстреливает `onActivityResult()`, который надо обработать примерно так:

```
if(requestCode==REQUEST_FOLDER && resultCode==RESULT_OK && intent!=null && intent.getData()!=null) {
        //retain folder read/write permissions
        ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContext().getContentResolver();
        int takeFlags = intent.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        Uri folderUri = intent.getData(); //uri каталога, в который будет разрешена запись
        contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(forlderUri, takeFlags);
}
```

3)Далее берем `folderUri` пишем туда все что хотим, примерно так:

```
DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, folderUri);
DocumentFile myFile = pickedDir.createFile("*/txt", "myfilename.txt"); 
//пишем в myFile
```

Comment: думаю TC тоже будет интересно: вы не разбирали такой вопрос - как потом найти свои файлы, когда приложение только что установлено, мы не знаем существуют ли ранее записанные нами файлы и где они лежат? Заставлять их искать юзера, который может и не понять чего от него требуют?

Comment: Нет, не разбирал. Наверное можно организовать поиск файлов с нужным расширением...

Comment: А чтобы искать по любому признаку, нужно просить разрешение на чтение :) Как по мне, так правильно просить юзера бэкапиться перед удалением и потом давать возможность восстанавливаться из бэкапа.

Comment: Вопрос то в том, где искать, как найти файл бэкапа?