# Доступ к внутренней памяти

Tags: java, android

Вопрос наверное уже давно заезженный...
Но ни как не могу разобраться, как сохранять и загружать файлы из внутренней памяти телефона. Именно та память, где находятся папки: Android, DCIM, Download, Movies, Music и т.д., а не внутреннее хранилище (память для приложения) или внешняя память (СД карта)

В манифест добавил:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

с помощью

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

мне удалось получить "/storage/emulated/0". Что это такое? Почему на ВМ (Nexus 5 API 25 и Pixel 3a API 30) при поиске в этой папке других папок, они, вроде как, находятся, а на моём honor 9x (Android ver. 10) не находятся.

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

возвращает 0.


Другими словами, я ищу следующую папку:

1. Включаю телефон, Нажимаю на значёк "Файлы", Выбираю место "Телефон", и вижу папки: Android, DCIM, Download, Movies, Music, Telegram, VK и ещё какие-то...
2. Подключаю тф к компу, выбираю передачу файлов, открывается папка,
   а в ней папка "Внутренняя память", а в ней те же папки, что и в п.1.

Comment: Какого рода ответ вы ожидаете? Скорее всего самым лучшим ответом будет ссылка на доку/статью, где это описывается. Скорее всего вы это уже видели. В итоге, получается, вам надо показать (правкой вопроса) какой информацией вы руководствовались, что у вас получилось, что нет и какие есть по этому поводу вопросы.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , подправил.

Comment: Вот тут можете посмотреть как можо очень большим кол-вом довольно сложного кода сохранить что-то в папку Downloads: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64357198/3212712 Простого доступа без рута вы не получите (на новых версиях ОС), т.к. гугл эту возможность ограничил довольно сильно. Возможно, вам надо пересмотреть подходы к решению не названной вами задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Пример получения папки **Downloads**

Из фрагмента

```
val downloadFolder = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
```

Из активити

```
val downloadFolder = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

Comment: использую: val downloadFolder = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS). возвращается: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.testtesttest/files/Pictures. Как понимаю, это "внутреннее хранилище", что я и не ищу.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь очень много терминологии :)

По прогерски:

1. *Internal storage* - это то что доступно только приложению - возвращается через `Context.getFilesDir()`
2. *External storage* - это все другое (не только SD карта, но также и внутреннее хранилище телефона)
3. *Primary External storage* - несьемная память аппарата
4. *Secondary External storage* - SD карта или USB носитель

По юзерски:

1. *Internal memory* - внутренняя память телефона
2. *External memory* - внешняя память телефона (SD карта, USB носитель и т.д.)

Так вот все доки/вызовы API трактуют именно прогерское понимание - учитывайте это.

Теперь к сути вопроса.

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` - уже довольно давно объявлен устаревшим. Сейчас все активно переходят на т.н. ScopedStorage.

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165323/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-android-api/1165331#1165331) или [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1208930/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-android-api-q-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/1208948#1208948)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно определиться с понятиями внутреннее или внешнее хранилище (или память).

Внешнее хранилище не означает, что это обязательно SD карта, хотя на старых Андроидах так и было и метод `getExternalFilesDir` мог вернуть `null`.
Принципиальное отличие состоит в том, что к папке `getFilesDir` имеет доступ только ваше приложение, а `getExternalFilesDir` все приложения и пользователь.

В них может находиться все, что угодно и это тоже не способ идентификации.

Comment: В моём понимании:<br> внутреннее хранилище - личная папка приложения, где она хранит свои данные; внешнее хранилище/память - СД карта; внутренняя память телефона - начиная с корневой директории